# How to print first element in list of string which is delimited by Pipe symbol in python

Tags: python, string, split, delimiter

How to get the first element from each pipe delimiter value.

```
test-123-2,abc,1232,,21,fd|lskd-929-8282,vbd,3221,,983,ew|ploi-90293-2,xsw,9073,,34,mn|opuye-8392-kl,few,45432,,234,df|
```

**For Example:** I want to print the output like this:

```
test-123-2
lskd-929-8282
ploi-90293-2
opuye-8392-kl
```

I tried something like this:

```
value=test-123-2,abc,1232,,21,fd|lskd-929-8282,vbd,3221,,983,ew|ploi-90293-2,xsw,9073,,34,mn|opuye-8392-kl,few,45432,,234,df|
result = value.split('|')
restult[0]
```

But its not coming the output which i expected. Can someone guide how can I print all first element in each column which is delimited by Pipe symbol

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine `split(',')` with `split('|')` like below:

```
res = [w.split(',')[0] for w in s.split('|')]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> for v in res[:-1]:
...     print(v)
... 
test-123-2
lskd-929-8282
ploi-90293-2
opuye-8392-kl
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do a double split, being careful with the empty values. Try this:

```
s = 'test-123-2,abc,1232,,21,fd|lskd-929-8282,vbd,3221,,983,ew|ploi-90293-2,xsw,9073,,34,mn|opuye-8392-kl,few,45432,,234,df|'
result = [data.split(',')[0] for data in s.split('|') if data]
```

Now `result` contains the expected values, so ya can do with them what you need to:

```
result
=> ['test-123-2', 'lskd-929-8282', 'ploi-90293-2', 'opuye-8392-kl']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, not so elegant way of doing it wihout using list comprehension is this:

```
test = "test-123-2,abc,1232,,21,fd|lskd-929-8282,vbd,3221,,983,ew|ploi-90293-2,xsw,9073,,34,mn|opuye-8392-kl,few,45432,,234,df|"

result = list(map(lambda y: y.split(',')[0], list(map(lambda x: x, test.split('|')))))

for r in result:
    print(r)
```

The result is:

```
test-123-2
lskd-929-8282
ploi-90293-2
opuye-8392-kl
```